# Orthigonal projections in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. $p$ is a projection in $M$, it is trivial that $1-p$ is orthogonal to $p$. Does there exist a largest projection $q\in M$ such that $qp=0$?

Comment: Well, given a closed subspace $U$ of a Hilbert space, does there exist a greatest (with respect to inclusion) subspace $V$ that is orthogonal to $U$? If the projection onto $U$ is in $M$, is the projection onto $V$ also in $M$?

Comment: Greatest in what sense?

Comment: I should use the term "largest". The order $\leq$ is defined as following: $p\leq q$ iff $0\leq p-p$.

Comment: Show that if $p$ and $q$ are self-adjoint projections and $qp=0$ then $p+q$ is a self-adjoint projection, so $p+q\le 1$, so $q\le 1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's $1-p$. If $q\geq 1-p$ and $qp=0$, then
$$
1-p=(1-p)q=q-pq=q. 
$$